# is this code correct?If yes then malloc is already assigning the addresses to name[i] variable then why strcpy is used?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, strcpy

Following is the piece of code

```
 char str[20];
 char *name[5];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     printf("Enter a string");
     gets(str);
     name[i]=(char *)malloc(strlen(str));
     strcpy(name[i],str);
 }
```

When in line 5 address of each string(denoted by `str` variable) is stored in `name[i]` array, then why this code is copying each address into `name[i]` using `strcpy()`?

Comment: You have to malloc strlen+1 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 5 merely allocates space. The memory allocated by `malloc()` has unspecified values.

Answer (score 4):

> *is this code correct?*

Sorry, No. Please follow the below mentioned points.

**Point 1**

Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

**Point 2**

`malloc()` is to *allocate* memory to the pointer. `strcpy()` is to *fill* the allocated memory. If you compare the code,

- `name[i]=malloc(<size>));`
  allocates memory of `size` bytes to `name[i]` pointer. but, the contains of the memory location is uninitialized or garbage.
- `strcpy(name[i],str);`
  it *copies* the containts of `str` to `name[i]`. After this, `name[i]` contains the same *string* as `str`.

**Note:**

That said, to `strcpy()` a string `str`, you need to `malloc()` for `strlen(str) + 1` bytes, to have space for terminating null. Otherwise, you'll end up overrunning the allocated memory area which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, you should (IMHO, *MUST*) consider using `fgets()` over `gets()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!By the way i am toddler in programming!

Answer (score 2):

The `strcpy()` call copies the characters, not the pointer.

Also, you are under-allocating since you fail to include space for the terminating `'\0'` character. Thus, your code has undefined behavior.

So no, it's not correct (but the problem is not that it uses `strcpy()`, that's fine).

And perhaps it's not surprising that I too think that you [should not cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Finally, you should never use `gets()`, it's very dangerous. Use `fgets()` instead, with a proper buffer size argument of course.

Answer (score 1):

When you use malloc, you create a space in memory that equals the size of the string, but is an empty space, you have only an address.
You have to copy the value on the string to the name[i] array.
An analogy is, you have a pot with water, you can create another pot, but you only will have water on it, if you transfer from one to another.
the creation of the pot is the malloc function and the transfer of the contents is the strcpy.

```
char str[6];                       //create a empty space for 6 characters

char *name[1];                     //create a pointer for a location where
                                   //the array will be stored, does not
                                   //allocate any space

str = "abcdef"                     //assign letters to character array

name[1]=(char *)malloc(strlen(str+1));     //name[1] = _ _ _ _ _ _ _
                                           //allocate space char array with
                                           //size equal to str array plus 1

strcpy(name[1],str);                       //name[1] = a b c d e f /0
                                           //copy the letters from one char
                                           //array to the other
```

character array has 6 characters plus a null character to indicate end of array

Comment: Interesting analogy... Can you edit your post to include a small code example as well? This helps reinforce your point further.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;

`malloc` assigns memory for the process to use.

`strcpy` copies the required content into the `malloc`ed address space.